# Spacy PhraseMatcher Value error Pattern length (11) >= phrase_matcher.max_length (10)

Tags: python, spacy

I am getting the following error when initializing a new PhraseMatcher with a list of terms:

> ValueError: Pattern length (11) >= phrase_matcher.max_length (10).
>   Length can be set on initialization, up to 10.

```
patterns = [nlp(org) for org in fields]
        self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
        self.matcher.add('FIELD', None, *patterns)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, a single rule cannot exceed 10 tokens in length:

```
# Allowed
'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten'
# Not Allowed
'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven'
```

You can try to set the limit higher, ie.: `self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, max_length=20)`, but iirc in the current release version of SpaCy 10 is a hard limit.

See relevant documentation at https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher#init and source at https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/spacy/matcher.pyx#L452

Comment: So you can pass a different parameter to the constructor, but it doesn't matter because there is an internal hardcoded limit to 10? :-S

Comment: See below Tahir Ahmad answer for real resolution.

Answer (score 1):

In spacy 2.1.4 version, the above ValueError for Phrase Matcher has been resolved. If you are getting such an error please update your spacy version.
refer: [github issue link](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1711)

Comment: This should be the chosen answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try define class as entity matcher and loop over various patterns/ fields

```
  class EntityMatcher(object):
       name = 'entity_matcher' 

  def __init__(self, nlp, terms, label): 
      patterns = [nlp(text) for text in terms] 
      self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab) 
      self.matcher.add(label, None, *patterns) 

  def __call__(self, doc): 
      matches = self.matcher(doc) 
      for match_id, start, end in matches: 
      span = Span(doc, start, end, label = match_id) 
      doc.ents = list(doc.ents) 

  return doc
```

Comment: Absolutely do not do this.